# Was there a previous version of tty_ldisc_ops.ioctl() that also required a file argument?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, tty, ioctl

I am porting some code that defined `tty_ldisc_ops.ioctl()` as:

```
static int ...ldisc_ioctl(struct tty_struct *tty, struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
```

But the [current spec](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/tty/tty_ldisc.html#c.tty_ldisc_ops) is:

```
static int ...ldisc_ioctl(struct tty_struct *tty, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
```

What happened to the "file" argument?  I looked for change logs and source.

---

I grabbed a random older kernel from (https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.1/).

```
int n_tty_ioctl(struct tty_struct * tty, struct file * file,
                       unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg) { ... tty->driver.ioctl(tty, file, cmd, arg); ...

tty.h, struct tty_struct { ... struct tty_driver driver; ...

tty_driver.h: struct tty_driver { ... int  (*ioctl)(struct tty_struct *tty, struct file * file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg); ...
```

Then the trail goes cold.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look tomorrow but it looks like omitting that argument should not cause any problems.

Comment: 0andriy, please post the answer so I can accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By browsing through the Git history of the Linux kernel project, you may find that v5.17 is the first one with the file being removed. [This commit](https://git.kernel.org/torvalds/c/d78328bcc4d0) made that happened. According to it you need to look for the previous patches, [one of which](https://lore.kernel.org/all/20210914091134.17426-5-jslaby@suse.cz/) seems explaining why that has been done:

> *The only user of 'file' parameter in tty_mode_ioctl is a BUG_ON check.
> Provided it never crashed for anyone, it's an overkill to pass the
> parameter to tty_mode_ioctl only for this check.*

So, in other words it was never used for anything related to the TTY layer and hence had been removed.